# Date format is showing incorrect date

Tags: php

I've got the following code:

```
$effectiveEndDate = date('o/m/d', $policy_end->getTimestamp());
```

`$policy_end` currently is set to this:

```
object(DateTime)#38 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-12-30 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(15) "America/Chicago"
}
```

However, when I output `$effectiveEndDate`, the value is `2020/12/30`. Why would the year change to 2020 rather than stay 2019?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], please? You question's off-topic without it.

Comment: Whats is ‘date(o/m/d)’ ?

Comment: You might find [this video](https://youtu.be/D3jxx8Yyw1c) enlightening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Documentation about 'o' format:

> ISO-8601 week-numbering year. This has the same value as Y, except that if the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, that year is used instead. (added in PHP 5.1.0)

It is because 30th december is closer to next year. Use 'Y' format instead.

[PHP: date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Tom Scott published a [video](https://youtu.be/D3jxx8Yyw1c) on YouTube this week, on exactly this topic.